# how to detect number of subnets on a network automatically

Tags: subnet, discovery

is any way to detect the number of subnets which are on my network and how to find them out automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use zero-config tools or utilities.

Comment: can u provide link plz ?

Comment: http://www.zeroconf.org/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any automated tools.
But you can try wireshark, set to filter the TCP packets only.
That will trow you a bit of light on what is going on in the LAN.